# average fraction of points from a set on a family of low degree curves over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, curves

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an finite field. Fix some enumeration of it, i.e. $\mathbb{F}=\{f_1,\dots,f_{|\mathbb{F}|}\}$, so that we can talk about the $i^{\text{th}}$ element in the field.

**Definition**: A degree $k$ curve over $\mathbb{F}^m$ is a mutlti-set
$$\{u_0+tu_1+\cdots+t^ku_k:t\in\mathbb{F}\}$$
where $u_0,\dots,u_k\in\mathbb{F}^m$.

Clearly, $\{u_0+tu_1+\cdots+t^ku_k:t\in\mathbb{F}\}=\{u_0+ctu_1+\cdots+c^kt^ku_k:t\in\mathbb{F}\}$ for every $c\in\mathbb{F}\setminus\{0\}$. So, we fix some canonical rep. for each curve.

Thanks to the enumeration defined on $\mathbb{F}$ we can talk about "the $i^{\text{th}}$ point" in a curve.

**Defintion**: Let $x_1,\dots,x_k\in\mathbb{F}^m$ (not necessarily distinct). The set $P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$ is the set of all degree $k$ curves over $\mathbb{F}^m$ whose first $k$ points are $x_1,\dots,x_k$.

**Problem**: Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{F}^m$ be any set and let $x_1,\dots,x_k\in\mathbb{F}^m$ (not all the same). Prove that the average of $\frac{|C\cap S|}{|C|}$ taken over all $C\in P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$, is $\frac{|S|}{|\mathbb{F}|^m}$, i.e. 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{|C\cap S|}{|C|}\right]=\frac{|S|}{|\mathbb{F}|^m}$$
where $C$ is uniformly drawn from $P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$.

**Initial Direction**: Someone told me to look at the following enumeration of $P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$:

For every $x\in\mathbb{F}^m$ and every $k<j\leq |\mathbb{F}|$ the curve in $P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$ whose $j^{\text{th}}$ point is $x$.

This counts each curve in $P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$ and each point in $\mathbb{F}^m$ exactly $|\mathbb{F}|-k$ times. But, I don't know how to proceed.

**Edit**: The lemma comes from a [paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/thesis.pdf), in page 156 of the pdf, the relevant claim is A.9, and it is primarily used in page 67 of the pdf.

Comment: What is your definition of an ordered finite field? Under the standard definition of an ordered field, a finite field cannot be ordered (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)).

Comment: @joriki Maybe I misused the word ordered. I only mean that for each element in the field you decide an index. So that we can talk about the first element, the second, the third and so on. Not order in the meaning of set theory, just an enumeration of the field.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're averaging over what. The sentence "Prove that the average $\frac{|C\cap S|}{|C|}$ taken over all $C\in P(\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle)$, is $\frac{|S|}{|\mathbb{F}|^m}$"? doesn't seem to make any sense, as the quantity you're averaging over appears as a free variable in the average. Perhaps there's an "of" missing after "average"?

Comment: @joriki Look at the last edit.

Comment: You've defined an enumeration of $\mathbb F$, but you use it on $\mathbb F^m$. Do you mean the lexical order on $\mathbb F^m$? Also, what do you mean by "first $k$ points" when the $x_i$ are explicitly not necessarily distinct? That the $x_i$ are the first points, however many they are?

Comment: @joriki I do not use it on $\mathbb{F}^m$. As a curve has a parametric rep. in a single variable $t$ that takes values in $\mathbb{F}$, the first point in the curve is the point where $t=f_1$, the second point of the curve is the point where $t=f_2$ and so on...

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.

Comment: The result seems to be false for $S=\{x_i\}$, where $|C\cap S|=|S|=1$ independent of $C$, so

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{|C\cap S|}{|C|}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac1{|C|}\right]\gt\frac1{|\mathbb{F}|^m}=\frac{|S|}{|\mathbb{F}|^m}\;?
$$

Comment: @joriki You are right! The lemma appears in  a paper I am reading in the area of complexity theory and it is either a mistake or a misunderstanding of mine of the lemma. The proof in the paper is too short and too vague for me...

Comment: In such a case it's always good to link to the paper so people can see the context first-hand.

Comment: @joriki I have added it, although I afraid it might not help much as it is deep inside the paper...

Comment: @DonFanucci Does the part just above the stateent of the lemma, which states this is dealing with **multi** sets, change anything here to your counterexample?

Comment: (also, just noting you [crossposted to CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46492/technical-lemma-about-curves-used-in-original-proof-of-pcp-theorem): try to avoid crossposting.)

Comment: @ClementC. But this allows the intersection to be even larger than size 1... Should I delete the post in CSTheory?

Comment: @DonFanucci Probably no need for now. OK, this is the morning, but is your "Problem" actually what the lemma states? The lemma seems to talk about $\mathbb{E}[|S\cap C|]$, not $\mathbb{E}[|S\cap C|/|C|]$, for a start.

Comment: @ClementC. Look at the use of the lemma in page 67 and see that it is used as I have stated it (they are talking about fraction of points and not total points). In fact it doesn't really matter as $|C|=|\mathbb{F}|$ for each curve $C$ because it is a multiset...

Comment: @DonFanucci Are we talking about the same pdf? I don't see where it is used in p.67 (which contains Claims 1 and 2).

Comment: @ClementC. here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/thesis.pdf in page 67 when counting in the pdf (in the paper it is page 57) at the bottom right before section 4.5 in the proof of the claim they use lemma A.9.

Comment: Honestly, I am confused at this point. It looks to me that at the very least the proof has conflicting/erroneous notation (or that I don't understand the notation well enough, e.g., the difference between $P(\langle x_1,..,x_k\rangle)$ and $\mathcal{C}$; I'm nearly sure one is used instead of the other in an erroneous way there), but that at the end of the day the argument relies on two ways of counting the same thing. Hopefully someone more familiar with the notions used there can help you (I would gather, on CSTheory).

Comment: @ClementC. Clearly, $\mathcal{C}$ should be replaced with $P(\langle x_1,..,x_k\rangle)$ ... However, this is not the main issue, this is just a typing error not a logical one, the rest of the argument has logical flaws...